# Conversion between nullptr and NULL

Tags: c++, c

I have some legacy code which was developed with C and will not be moved to C++. But I have a application written on top of this C code making use of function calls.

From C++11, proper usage is to use `nullptr` in place of `NULL`.

What happens when I pass `nullptr` in one of the function calls made to C from C++ ? Will that be converted to `NULL` when received at C. Or on those function calls made to C application, should we pass only `NULL` though written in C++ ?